# Between variables sql

Tags: sql, vlookup, between, xlookup

I've been thinking about this but didn't get a solution yet.

I have 2 tables

TABLE1

```
FrID FrCode Zstart  ZEnd
-------------------------
1      AQ   10000   20000
2      AW   34578   67459
3      SR   86428   89758
```

TABLE2

```
ID NAME ZIP
-------------
1  XXX  35864
2  CCC  25758
3  FFF  87526
```

I need to get the `frCode` if the `ZIP` is between `Zstart` and `ZEnd`.

The problem is that I don't have a primary key to joint the tables.
I know a between clause can help but not sure how to do for all values.

Note: `Id` and `FrID` are not key values

Answer (score 0):

Between is a common SQL construct to use for querying between date ranges so to get frCode between start and end you can do something like below

```
SELECT t1.FrCode
FROM TABLE1 t1
JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.FrID = t2.ID
WHERE t2.ZIP BETWEEN t1.Zstart AND t1.ZEnd
```

If the FrID and ID are not related, then there must be some relation between Table1 and Table2 right if you want to get FrCode then you will need to join on that relation

```
ON t1.FrID = t2.OtherColumn
```

Comment: Thank you, that would work if I'd were keys but in my case they are not. Those are independiente IDs

Comment: Ok I missed that part, so FrID and ID are not related, then is Table1 and Table 2 related in any way at all?

Comment: no, that's the big problem